# After updating a react native app, trigger an action before app launch (clean persistent store in my case)

Tags: react-native, redux

I modified some redux store (using redux-persist) logic in my app, and when a user update the app, at the first launch he get a crash because of inconsistency between the previous store and my new code. If the user relaunch the app everything is fine.

How can i detect that this is the first launch of an updated app version, clean the store and then render the app with new store initialization ?

I know how to clean the store, the part i struggle with is the way to know if the app just got updated and it's the very first launch. I don't want to clean at every launch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you’re using Expo to build your app you could get get around this by using the Updates module from Expo. Create a condition to only persist the store/or load redux after update is completed.

Comment: i'm not using expo unfortunately :/